# Sci-fi/fantasy story about luck encapsulated in jewelry or charms

Tags: story-identification

I’m on a quest to rediscover a short story (or possibly a book) I read some time ago I think in the 1990s but can’t seem to recall the title or author. The central premise is both intriguing and unique: all the luck in the world has been captured and bottled up into jewelry or charms. These powerful items are then hoarded by the wealthy, creating a stark division between the fortunate elite and the luckless rest.

Here are a few more details to help narrow it down:

- Genre: It straddles the lines between science fiction and fantasy.
- Plot Details: The story explores the societal and personal ramifications of luck being a tangible, purchasable commodity.
- Themes: It delves into themes of inequality, fate, and the human desire to control one’s destiny.
- Publication Date: I’m not sure when it was published, probably 1990s or earlier.

Comment: Tough one. Any more clues to help narrow the search? Did you read it in English? UK, Aus/NZ, US? Beyond the premise, was there a plot - someone stealing jewels? A protagonist looking for luck?